# User Input - Scanner Skips user inptu

Tags: java

This is a simple test I made for my user input of my program but it skips over the second user input part. I am using sc.nextLine()

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option;
    String name;

    System.out.println("1 or 2");
    option = sc.nextInt();

    if(option == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a name");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: The program prints "1 or 2" The user selects 1 then the program prints the "please enter a name" theres a gap and the program ends??????

Comment: it's a classic issue. After your nextInt(); call, add another sc.next();

Comment: What do you mean wont that just ask for user input again?

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: I get what you are saying because thats to do with clearing the buffer? But if I put sc.next(); straight after the sc.nextInt(); it asks for user input again?

Comment: @NightPixel it will treat the enter.

Comment: @Stultuske `next()` __doesn't__ treat the enter/return. You're confusing it with `nextLine()` (or it was a typo in your first comment).

Comment: @Tom you're right. Haven't used scanner for over a decade, I recognized the behavior, but ... :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the enter ("\n") from the first user input isn't a number and is used for the second.
The quick and dirty option to fix this is to add a "sc.nextLine ();" after "nextInt()" line.
Like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option;
    String name;

    System.out.println("1 or 2");
    option = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    if(option == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a name");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok sc.nextLine(); worked thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use `sc.nextLine()` after `sc.nextInt()` in your code.

Comment: nope, that line is not the issue. It's expecting and end of line after the nextInt();

Comment: updated that in the code.